# how to change a value inside a array of obejcts

Tags: javascript, arrays

My array looks like,

```
[
   {
      "lat":68.40928899869893,
      "lng":39.548560173006884
   },
   {
      "lat":45.35600542155823,
      "lng":32.5203664592608
   },
   {
      "lat":48.94054322456003,
      "lng":102.45089391103468
   },
   {
      "lat":70.14969277620159,
      "lng":96.8283389400378
   }
]
```

I need to change the `lat` and `lng` to **Lat** and **Long**

What I tried,

```
  coords[0].map((coord) => {
    coord.replace("lat", "Lat");
    coord.replace("lng", "long");
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried to (1) do it on the whole array (instead of only the index-0 element) and (2) to return a new object with the new keys in the map callback?

Comment: `replace` returns a new string. It won't edit it in place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map()` is the right tool.  But instead of thinking of this as modifying or replacing properties on each object, think of it has projecting the array into a new array.  For example:

```js
const myArr = [
   {
      "lat":68.40928899869893,
      "lng":39.548560173006884
   },
   {
      "lat":45.35600542155823,
      "lng":32.5203664592608
   },
   {
      "lat":48.94054322456003,
      "lng":102.45089391103468
   },
   {
      "lat":70.14969277620159,
      "lng":96.8283389400378
   }
];

const newArr = myArr.map(c => ({
  Lat: c.lat,
  Long: c.lng
}));

console.log(newArr);
```

So each iteration of `.map()` doesn't *change* the object, it creates a *new* object in whatever structure you like.

Comment: It only takes the first coords. `[
   {
      "Lat":66.37330109064273,
      "Long":43.20302957642014
   }
]`

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas: Can you provide more context for that?  The code here demonstrably does what's expected, running the code snippet and observing the results shows that.  What code have *you* written instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the array `map()` function

```js
const cords = [
   {
      "lat":68.40928899869893,
      "lng":39.548560173006884
   },
   {
      "lat":45.35600542155823,
      "lng":32.5203664592608
   },
   {
      "lat":48.94054322456003,
      "lng":102.45089391103468
   },
   {
      "lat":70.14969277620159,
      "lng":96.8283389400378
   }
]

const newCords = cords.map((cord) => ({Lat: cord.lat, Long: cord.lng}))

console.log(newCords);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to modify the original array as well.

```js
coords.map(coord => {
    let [lat, lng] = [coord.lat, coord.lng];
    delete coord.lat;
    delete coord.lng;
    coord['Lat'] = lat;
    coord['long'] = lng;
    return coord;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to update your original is as below

**Logic**

- Loop through the array
- Assign the value of `lat` from that object to `Lat` and `lng` to `long` in the same object
- Delete `lat` and `lng` keys from the object

```js
const cooordinates = [
  {
    "lat": 68.40928899869893,
    "lng": 39.548560173006884
  },
  {
    "lat": 45.35600542155823,
    "lng": 32.5203664592608
  },
  {
    "lat": 48.94054322456003,
    "lng": 102.45089391103468
  },
  {
    "lat": 70.14969277620159,
    "lng": 96.8283389400378
  }
]

cooordinates.forEach((node) => {
    node['Lat'] = node['lat'];
    node['long'] = node['lng'];
    delete node['lat'];
    delete node['lng'];
});

console.log(cooordinates);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of changing property names

```js
let arr = [
   {
      "lat":68.40928899869893,
      "lng":39.548560173006884
   },
   {
      "lat":45.35600542155823,
      "lng":32.5203664592608
   },
   {
      "lat":48.94054322456003,
      "lng":102.45089391103468
   },
   {
      "lat":70.14969277620159,
      "lng":96.8283389400378
   }
]

arr.forEach(obj => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(prop => {
        if (prop === 'lng') {
            obj["long"] = obj[prop];
            delete obj[prop];
        }
        if (prop === 'lat') {
            obj["Lat"] = obj[prop];
            delete obj[prop];
        }
    });
});

console.log(arr)
```